# Mysql: Select number of transactions from 1 week ago

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
transactions
+------------+------------+ 
| date_id    | t_count    | 
+------------+------------+ 
| 2019-01-30 |       100  | 
| 2019-01-29 |        99  | 
| 2019-01-28 |        98  | 
| 2019-01-27 |        97  | 
| 2019-01-26 |        96  | 
| 2019-01-25 |        95  | 
| 2019-01-24 |        94  | 
| 2019-01-23 |        93  | 
| 2019-01-22 |        92  | 
| 2019-01-21 |        91  | 
| 2019-01-20 |        90  | 
+------------+------------+
```

I would like to get t_count for the date as well as t_count for one week prior, like so:

```
+------------+------------+------------------+ 
| date_id     | t_count   | t_count_7d_prev  | 
+------------+------------+------------------+ 
| 2019-01-30 |       100  |              93  | 
| 2019-01-29 |        99  |              92  | 
| 2019-01-28 |        98  |              91  | 
| 2019-01-27 |        97  |              90  | 
+------------+------------+------------------+
```

I've tried the following query but it gives me nulls for the last column.

```
select
  date_id,
  t_count,
  (select t_count 
   from transactions 
   where date(date_id) = date(date_id) - interval 7 day) as t_count_7d_prev
from 
  transactions
```

Is there another way that I should try subtracting the dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  If `date_id` is a date:

```
select date_id, t_count,
       sum(t_count) over (order by date_id
                          range between interval 7 day preceding and interval 7 day preceding
                         ) as t_count_7d_prev
from transactions t;
```

Or, if you are sure you have data every date, then use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(t_count, 7) over (order by date_id) as t_count_7d_prev
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple internal join.

```
select a.date_id, a.t_count, b.t_count as t_count_7d_prev
from
    transactions a left join transaction b
    on a.dat_id = DATE_ADD(b.date_id,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```